# Fieldbook Codelet - Not returning all matching records

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, for-loop

I am creating a codelet in fieldbook for a slackbot. It is meant to return all records that match the date requested in slack. Right now it is setup to only return the first record, but I need all of them. I am fairly new to this, I apologize if this is a basic question, but any help would be great. Below is what I have so far.

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var s = require('underscore.string');

exports.endpoint = exports.endpoint = function (request, response) {
   var jobDate = request.body.text;
   // Get the date from Job Notes
   var date = `${(jobDate)}`;

   // Find all records with the given date
   var query = {date: date};
   return client.list('job_notes', query).then(function (records) {
       // This is only pulling the first record
```

I need all the records that match the date given, this is where I believe I need a for loop.

```
       var record = records[0];

       if (!record) return `No data found for ${jobDate}`; // Did not match any record

       var employee = record.employee[0];
       var job = record.job[0];

       var attributes = [
         {title: 'Date', value:date, short: true},
         {title: 'Time', value:record.time, short: true},
         {title: 'Employees', value:employee, short: true},
         {title: 'Job', value:job, short: true},
         {title: 'Note', value:record.note, short: true},
       ];

       return {
         attachments: [{
           fallback: record.name,
           title: record.name,
           fields: attributes,
       }]
     }
   })
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your question has to do with iterating through the list of items passed in the variable `records` in a for loop.  This can be done with the following code:

```
return client.list('job_notes', query).then(function(records) {
    for (i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
        var record = records[i];

        if (!record) return `No data found for ${jobDate}`; // Did not match any record

        var employee = record.employee[0];
        var job = record.job[0];

        var attributes = [
            {title: 'Date', value:date, short: true},
            {title: 'Time', value:record.time, short: true},
            {title: 'Employees', value:employee, short: true},
            {title: 'Job', value:job, short: true},
            {title: 'Note', value:record.note, short: true},
        ];


        return {
            attachments: [{
                fallback: record.name,
                title: record.name,
                fields: attributes,
            }]
        }
    }
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out and let you know. I appreciate the quick response!